# page first event fails to work after validation fails in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms, customvalidator

I`m experiencing weird problem in my page , in my page i have many controls and for all of them i have asp.net validators , i had 1 validation summery and everything worked fined but i changed the page to have 4 validation summery for better UI experience and i check validations in on button in client side like this

```
function validatePage() {
        //Executes all the validation controls associated with group1 validaiton Group1. 
        var flag = window.Page_ClientValidate('pInfo');
        if (flag)
            //Executes all the validation controls associated with group1 validaiton Group2. 
            flag = window.Page_ClientValidate('heiatElmi');
        if (flag)
            //Executes all the validation controls associated with group1 validaiton Group3. 
            flag = window.Page_ClientValidate('eduGroup');
        if (flag)
            //Executes all the validation controls associated with group1 validaiton Group3. 
            flag = window.Page_ClientValidate('contact');
        if (flag)
            //Executes all the validation controls which are not associated with any validation group. 
            flag = window.Page_ClientValidate();
        return flag;
    }
```

my problem is since i changed to this multi summery pattern first asyncpostback of my page fails to work , in my page i using multiple updatepanels and ms ajax for async ajax calls .
does anyone know why first event after validation fails not working ?
Note : I`m using telerik component for some of page functionalities.